# How to read csv in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, input

I just start using TensorFlow. I am trying to read csv file in TensorFlow. This is an example I found online:

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["d:/Feng/LP/tensorflowtrydata.csv"])
reader = tf.TextLineReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
record_defaults = [[1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], ["Null"]] 
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 = tf.decode_csv(value,record_defaults=record_defaults) 
features = tf.stack([col1, col2, col3, col4])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    for i in range(200):
        example, label = sess.run([features, col5])
        print (example,col5)
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

But I have the error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Field 0 in record 0 is not a valid float: Sepal.Length
 [[Node: DecodeCSV_5 = DecodeCSV[OUT_TYPE=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_STRING], field_delim=",", na_value="", use_quote_delim=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](ReaderReadV2_3:1, DecodeCSV_5/record_defaults_0, DecodeCSV_5/record_defaults_0, DecodeCSV_5/record_defaults_0, DecodeCSV_5/record_defaults_0, DecodeCSV_5/record_defaults_4)]]
```

The data is iris dataset. It looks like:

```
iris.head()
   Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width  Petal.Length  Petal.Width Species
0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa
1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa
2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa
3           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  setosa
4           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  setosa
iris.dtypes
Sepal.Length    float64
Sepal.Width     float64
Petal.Length    float64
Petal.Width     float64
Species          object
```

You can see that the error info said that it is not a valid float. But all the data are float64.

I am not even sure where to start with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion is that `iris.head()` provides first 5 lines of df **AFTER** header has been handled. Whereas in tensorflow, as you can see in the error line:
`Field 0 in record 0 is not a valid float: ﻿Sepal.Length`, header is not automatically handled and thus *Sepal.Length*, the string, is causing the problem.

You can either use `pandas.read_csv` to first import file then transform into whatever tensorflow wants, or use some options in like:

```
reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_line=1)
```